# How to correctly add Unity references to access the "rotate" method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What reference should I add to access the method `rotate`?

Here are my current `using` directives:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
```

[image]

Comment: not that your question isn't welcome here, but Unity has its own question/answer site: http://answers.unity3d.com/

Comment: @DLeh  what makes you think it will receive more appreciation on answers.unity3d.com?

Comment: @JanDvorak my mistake, I won't provide other resources that might help the question again.

Answer (score 0):

With a `using UnityEngine;`you're good to go. However, there is no method called `rotate`. That is, not in the way you're trying to use it now.

[`Rotate(Vector3 eulerAngles, Space relativeTo = Space.Self)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) (note the capitalization) is not static. So you don't call it as `Transform.Rotate(...)`, but you call it upon an actual `Transform` instance. If we're talking about the GameObject your component is attached to, then it would look something like `transform.Rotate(...);`.

If you try that, I'm sure it should show up.